# Como criar uma activity onde o usuário possa criar um perfil no aplicativo

Tags: android, firebase

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo e nesse aplicativo o usuário poderá criar um perfil para ele, com o seu nome, foto, email, etc.

Minha dúvida é essa parte da foto, como faço para inserir algum elemento no layout onde o usuário possa inserir uma foto a partir da memória do celular? Estou utilizando o FireBase como WebService.

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13247/35406